# Issues in converting rb file to exe file

Tags: exe

I am using OCRA to convert my rb file to exe file. The script runs ok and it creates an exe file as well. However, when I send the exe file to a user to run (without ruby install in his system), he faces the following error in between the exe run.. "Windows can't find rubyw. Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again. To search for a file, click the Start button , and then click Search"...

Has anyone faced this issue before?

I tried installing Exerb and then gave the following command: ruby -r exerb/mkexy 234.rb. However, it created a file with .exy extension with size < 1KB.

I truly appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Experienced a similar problem with a standalone Ruby package. The problem is due to the fact that your ruby is standalone and some of the code is using ruby for running some code as if the ruby was installed, it could be your own code, or most likely the gems. I can only point you to the right direction. Probably there is a system call which is executing something like `system("start rubyw blah_blah_blah")`, notice 'rubyw' is dependant on you having a path specified. It could be a little problematic when rubyw is being executed because there is no way to see the exception stack trace. After spending some time debugging and looking at what exactly is being executed, I found that some of the istalled gems are using rubyw to fork off a process and that caused my problem... Hope it was useful.